# I cannot update my computer with the GUI updater due failure of internet

Tags: networking, updates, internet, 16.04

I opened the GUI update manager to update. But it gave this window:

[image]

So I clicked try again, and it did the same. Then I clicked Settings... To see if I'd broken something.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I could not see an issue. I did notice that some source code was downloading. I didn't want it to. So I unticked the source code ones, and then clicked Close. It gave this window:

[image]

So I reloaded it and it gave this error:

[image]

[Under details was this paste](http://paste.ubuntu.com/16013614/).

Note that I do have an internet connection. I can install:

```
tim@Hairy16:~$ apt install traceroute
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Get:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 traceroute amd64 1:2.0.21-1 [45.5 kB]
Fetched 45.5 kB in 0s (280 kB/s)    
Selecting previously unselected package traceroute.
(Reading database ... 158453 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../traceroute_1%3a2.0.21-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking traceroute (1:2.0.21-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up traceroute (1:2.0.21-1) ...
```

traceroute Google:

```
tim@Hairy16:~$ traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (216.58.198.110), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  dsldevice.lan (192.168.1.254)  11.259 ms  11.259 ms  11.304 ms
 2  lo0-central10.pcl-ag05.plus.net (195.166.128.186)  29.279 ms  29.496 ms  30.662 ms
 3  link-a-central10.pcl-gw01.plus.net (212.159.2.176)  30.736 ms  30.807 ms  30.874 ms
 4  xe-1-2-0.pcl-cr01.plus.net (212.159.0.208)  34.146 ms  34.217 ms  34.886 ms
 5  ae2.pcl-cr02.plus.net (195.166.129.7)  36.757 ms ae1.ptw-cr01.plus.net (195.166.129.0)  35.837 ms ae2.pcl-cr02.plus.net (195.166.129.7)  36.820 ms
 6  72.14.222.97 (72.14.222.97)  36.585 ms  16.235 ms ae1.ptw-cr02.plus.net (195.166.129.2)  17.139 ms
 7  72.14.223.32 (72.14.223.32)  17.047 ms  30.030 ms  24.532 ms
 8  64.233.174.113 (64.233.174.113)  24.435 ms 64.233.175.155 (64.233.175.155)  26.854 ms 64.233.174.83 (64.233.174.83)  26.929 ms
 9  64.233.175.155 (64.233.175.155)  26.271 ms  27.269 ms lhr25s07-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.198.110)  26.737 ms
```

and ping Google:

```
tim@Hairy16:~$ ping google.com
PING google.com (216.58.208.142) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lhr25s08-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.208.142): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=12.5 ms
64 bytes from lhr25s08-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.208.142): icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=12.4 ms
64 bytes from lhr25s08-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.208.142): icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=87.8 ms
64 bytes from lhr25s08-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.208.142): icmp_seq=4 ttl=55 time=12.6 ms
64 bytes from lhr25s08-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.208.142): icmp_seq=5 ttl=55 time=118 ms
64 bytes from lhr25s08-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.208.142): icmp_seq=6 ttl=55 time=12.2 ms
--- google.com ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5007ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 12.291/42.734/118.675/43.701 ms
```

How can I update via the GUI?

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/16014048/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your /etc/apt/sources.list file might have duplicate entries in from what I can see in the pastebin. I would manually remove the lines using a text editor like nano or gedit.

And the failed to download repository information is being caused by having a non existant repository in the sources.list file - it looks like that the extras repository doesn't exist for Xenial yet. Removing the line
`deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main` 
should fix updating.

I would also do 'apt-get clean' as well afterwards.